# python subprocess does not write to stdout

Tags: python, subprocess

If I run the following python code (in python 2.7) I get an empty output file while I would expect a line. What is wrong?

```
import subprocess

with open('outfile.out', 'w') as out:
   pp=subprocess.Popen(['/bin/cat'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=out)
   pp.stdin.write('Line I want into out file\n')
   pp.terminate()
```

Answer (score 2):

You `terminate`d the process, and never flushed/closed the input to it, so all the data was stuck in buffers and discarded when the process was forcibly killed. You can use `communicate` to combine passing input, closing `stdin`, then waiting for the process to complete:

```
import subprocess

with open('outfile.out', 'w') as out:
   pp=subprocess.Popen(['/bin/cat'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=out)
   pp.communicate('Line I want into out file\n')
```

In this case (only one of the three standard handles is a pipe), you could also do this safely:

```
import subprocess

with open('outfile.out', 'w') as out:
   pp=subprocess.Popen(['/bin/cat'],stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=out)
   pp.stdin.write('Line I want into out file\n')
   pp.stdin.close()
   pp.wait()  # Optionally with a timeout, calling terminate if it doesn't join quickly
```

That should only be done if you are only using a single standard handle as `PIPE`; if more than one is `PIPE`, there is a risk of deadlock (child is writing to stdout, waiting for you to read to clear the buffer, you are writing to stdin, waiting for child to read to clear the buffer) that `communicate` resolves by using threads or the select module, and you'd have to mimic that design to avoid deadlock.

Comment: use `pp.wait()` instead of `pp.join()` (it is `subprocess`, not `multiprocessing`). There is no `timeout` parameter in Python 2.7 (unless you use `subprocess32` module).

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Fixed the `wait` vs. `join` bit; your comment can clarify when `timeout` is available.